# facebook type wall post script

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables  members_tbl and post_tbl

members_tbl:

id|userName |fname |lname |friendArray

post_tbl:

postId| memId | thePost |postDate

now, I'm trying to display post from user id and from his friendArray.
please let me know how to do it (still new to php)

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried? Do you have your mysql query? Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO` to connect?

Comment: Have you made any attempts to do this?

Comment: How are you storing the friend array?

Comment: $sql_posts = mysql_query("SELECT  id, mem_id, the_post, post_date,device FROM posts WHERE mem_id IN('$id','$friend_array') ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 30");

Comment: We are not a script generator website. Please show us your code, what problem (if any) you are encountering.. Desired output & Actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MySQL lacks an `explode` function, you either need to create a relation table and use joins, or use multiple queries with php processing inbetween. I **strongly** recommend the relational approach as it conforms to database standards (normalization) much more than the alternative and is easier to implement.

You need a third table, which describes the relation between two friends, I.E.

```
friends_tbl
user1_id | user2_id
```

With a primary key on `user1_id` and `user2_id` (thereby preventing duplicates). For every friend relationship, I.E. user 1 is friends with user 2, there is one row in this table. You can then get the listing you want with the following query.

```
SELECT p.*, u.*
FROM posts_tbl p
INNER JOIN members_tbl u
  ON u.id = p.memId
WHERE u.id IN (
  SELECT user2_id AS id
  FROM friends_tbl
  INNER JOIN members_tbl
  ON (user1_id = id)
  WHERE members_tbl.id = $id

  UNION

  SELECT user1_id AS id
  FROM friends_tbl
  INNER JOIN members_tbl
  ON (user2_id = id)
  WHERE members_tbl.id = $id
)
ORDER BY p.postDate
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2acd1/1) of the above.

Answer (score 0):

create a different table for your friend-relations and then join this table in your SQL.